# How to check whether gcnew failed or not?

Tags: c++-cli, heap-memory

Does `gcnew` throw an exception or set variable to `nullptr` when it fails to allocate memory?

Comment: It never returns nullptr, it throw OutOfMemoryException when it fails.  Catching it is invariably pointless, just make sure you have a decent event handler for the AppDomain::CurrentDomain->UnhandledException event so your user knows why your program blew up.